# Requirements for understanding Blogger Template Editing (XML)

Tags: xml, templates, blogger

I am new to blogger template data tags (XML tags) like

data:post.link

I want to learn the technique used in blogger.com template. 
I have good knowledge on C,C++,Java,VB,C#,php
But not in XML.

I don't need any code.
Just want to know where i can start from!

I recently find many helping sites but all are with lack of information. All sites are just showing how can i use the predefined block of codes.

I want to learn not copy and paste.

Sorry for my BAD ENGLISH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, As long as you know HTML, you are able to write a blogger template and you will learn most if you read through templates and find out what things do. Base your code on others first and then you can build from there.
If you want to know what every data tag means maybe check out [this documentation](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en)

There are also a few other posts on there that specify the specific stuff like writing variables for the template designer etc, but most of it will be easy to understand, once you read through the code of an actual template.

But to be honest, when it comes to the data-tags there is not a lot of freedom, what really makes a template individual is the html surrounding it.

That's why I usually start off with [Five](https://github.com/5202/five/blob/classic_comments/five.xml) (an empty, clutterfree blogger template)  and build my template around it. I find myself using some data and conditional tags, but can honestly not be bothered to much about things like data:post.title etc because it basically just tells Blogger to add the link within my h1-tag.

Comment: I know data tags has its limitation. But is their no help available to understand it so that i can use my own custom if else logic , filter post, filter comments, etc... I mean to say conditioning the tags..

Comment: The only help I have found so far is the link to the documentation.
What are you trying to do, maybe I can help if I know an example.
Maybe also have a look at the blogger conditional tags, even though I have not found any documentation from Google. and the only good post I know about them is in German...